# Receving data form using HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream,chinese encoding wrong(The same code,why the result is not the same?)

Tags: java, encoding, character, httprequest, httpurlconnection

everybody:
    I try to make a httpRequest for getting data,there's something wrong while response contain chinese characters.I got a String with HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()(see /*test code.*/),I have wrote a main method on my local environment to test this code.And it works well!But when I startup my project,using this code for requesting data,the problem came out...(from the system.out below we can see the chinese characters are wrong )I don't understand why it cant be translate into write encoding.
  And when I copy (/*test code.*/) to static main method and run it,it seems no any problem,right?The same code,why the result is not the same?
my computer environment : win7,project and tomcat all use utf-8,request and response encoding both utf-8,too.
Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;



public class HttpRequestUtil {
    private String defaultContentEncoding;  

    public HttpRequestUtil() {  
        this.defaultContentEncoding = Charset.defaultCharset().name();  
    }  

    public HttpRequestUtil(String encoding) {  
        this.defaultContentEncoding = encoding;  
    } 

    /** 
     * 发送GET请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     *            URL地址 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public HttpResponsUtil sendGet(String urlString) throws IOException {  
        return this.send(urlString, "GET", null, null);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 发送GET请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     *            URL地址 
     * @param params 
     *            参数集合 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public HttpResponsUtil sendGet(String urlString, Map<String, String> params)  
            throws IOException {  
        return this.send(urlString, "GET", params, null);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 发送GET请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     *            URL地址 
     * @param params 
     *            参数集合 
     * @param propertys 
     *            请求属性 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public HttpResponsUtil sendGet(String urlString, Map<String, String> params,  
            Map<String, String> propertys) throws IOException {  
        return this.send(urlString, "GET", params, propertys);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 发送POST请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     *            URL地址 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public HttpResponsUtil sendPost(String urlString) throws IOException {  
        return this.send(urlString, "POST", null, null);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 发送POST请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     *            URL地址 
     * @param params 
     *            参数集合 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public HttpResponsUtil sendPost(String urlString, Map<String, String> params)  
            throws IOException {  
        return this.send(urlString, "POST", params, null);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 发送POST请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     *            URL地址 
     * @param params 
     *            参数集合 
     * @param propertys 
     *            请求属性 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public HttpResponsUtil sendPost(String urlString, Map<String, String> params,  
            Map<String, String> propertys) throws IOException {  
        return this.send(urlString, "POST", params, propertys);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 发送HTTP请求 
     *  
     * @param urlString 
     * @return 响映对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    private HttpResponsUtil send(String urlString, String method,  
            Map<String, String> parameters, Map<String, String> propertys)  
            throws IOException {  
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;  

        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET") && parameters != null) {  
            StringBuffer param = new StringBuffer();  
            int i = 0;  
            for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {  
                if (i == 0)  
                    param.append("?");  
                else  
                    param.append("&");  
                param.append(key).append("=").append(parameters.get(key));  
                i++;  
            }  
            urlString += param;  
        }  
        URL url = new URL(urlString);  
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);  
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);  
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);  

        if (propertys != null)  
            for (String key : propertys.keySet()) {  
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty(key, propertys.get(key));  
            }  

        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST") && parameters != null) {  
            StringBuffer param = new StringBuffer();  
            for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {  
                param.append("&");  
                param.append(key).append("=").append(parameters.get(key));  
            }  
            urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(param.toString().getBytes());  
            urlConnection.getOutputStream().flush();  
            urlConnection.getOutputStream().close();  
        }  

        return this.makeContent(urlString, urlConnection);  
    }  

    /** 
     * 得到响应对象 
     *  
     * @param urlConnection 
     * @return 响应对象 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    private HttpResponsUtil makeContent(String urlString,  
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException {  
        HttpResponsUtil httpResponser = new HttpResponsUtil();  
        try {  
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();  
            //这里如果不指定InputStreamReader的编码，当中文字符超过两个时就会出现乱码（utf8情况下）
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(  
                    new InputStreamReader(in, this.defaultContentEncoding));  
            httpResponser.contentCollection = new Vector<String>();  
            StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();  
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();  
            while (line != null) {  
                httpResponser.contentCollection.add(line);  
                temp.append(line);  //.append("\r\n")
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();  
            }  
            bufferedReader.close();  

            String ecod = urlConnection.getContentEncoding();  
            if (ecod == null){
                ecod = this.defaultContentEncoding;
                httpResponser.content = temp.toString();
                /*test code.*/
                System.out.println("ecod is" + ecod);
                //ecod isUTF-8
                System.out.println("temp = " + temp.toString());
                //temp = {"tags":[{"r_id":3553740735078269,"tag":"再测试"},{"r_id":3555331928010955,"tag":"再测试"},{"r_id":3555332033148401,"tag":"再测试,测试好多个字符串"}],"rids":"3555332033148401,3555331928010955,3553740735078269,3553509628288136,3552801450193593,3550638895838037,3550607615227068,3550334377352366,3550333965816322,3550315184067715,3550136490112256,3550098295918936,3550094449884887,3550094122996559,3550092986220398,3550090717120421,3550090532251655,3550089362475695,3549897523877864,3549756045751486,3549719639064459,3549564726035910,3549379539997223,3549377979585685,3549373109656624","idArr":["3555332033148401","3555331928010955","3553740735078269","3553509628288136","3552801450193593","3550638895838037","3550607615227068","3550334377352366","3550333965816322","3550315184067715","3550136490112256","3550098295918936","3550094449884887","3550094122996559","3550092986220398","3550090717120421","3550090532251655","3550089362475695","3549897523877864","3549756045751486","3549719639064459","3549564726035910","3549379539997223","3549377979585685","3549373109656624"],"uId":1916364215,"type":3}
                System.out.println("temp after encode: "+new String(temp.toString().getBytes(), ecod));
                //temp after encode: {"tags":[{"r_id":3553740735078269,"tag":"?????"},{"r_id":3555331928010955,"tag":"?????"},{"r_id":3555332033148401,"tag":"?????,??????????"}],"rids":"3555332033148401,3555331928010955,3553740735078269,3553509628288136,3552801450193593,3550638895838037,3550607615227068,3550334377352366,3550333965816322,3550315184067715,3550136490112256,3550098295918936,3550094449884887,3550094122996559,3550092986220398,3550090717120421,3550090532251655,3550089362475695,3549897523877864,3549756045751486,3549719639064459,3549564726035910,3549379539997223,3549377979585685,3549373109656624","idArr":["3555332033148401","3555331928010955","3553740735078269","3553509628288136","3552801450193593","3550638895838037","3550607615227068","3550334377352366","3550333965816322","3550315184067715","3550136490112256","3550098295918936","3550094449884887","3550094122996559","3550092986220398","3550090717120421","3550090532251655","3550089362475695","3549897523877864","3549756045751486","3549719639064459","3549564726035910","3549379539997223","3549377979585685","3549373109656624"],"uId":1916364215,"type":3}
                String str = "{\"tags\":[{\"r_id\":3553740735078269,\"tag\":\"再测试\"},{\"r_id\":3555331928010955,\"tag\":\"再测试\"},{\"r_id\":3555332033148401,\"tag\":\"再测试,测试好多个字符串\"}],\"rids\":\"3555332033148401,3555331928010955,3553740735078269,3553509628288136,3552801450193593,3550638895838037,3550607615227068,3550334377352366,3550333965816322,3550315184067715,3550136490112256,3550098295918936,3550094449884887,3550094122996559,3550092986220398,3550090717120421,3550090532251655,3550089362475695,3549897523877864,3549756045751486,3549719639064459,3549564726035910,3549379539997223,3549377979585685,3549373109656624\",\"idArr\":[\"3555332033148401\",\"3555331928010955\",\"3553740735078269\",\"3553509628288136\",\"3552801450193593\",\"3550638895838037\",\"3550607615227068\",\"3550334377352366\",\"3550333965816322\",\"3550315184067715\",\"3550136490112256\",\"3550098295918936\",\"3550094449884887\",\"3550094122996559\",\"3550092986220398\",\"3550090717120421\",\"3550090532251655\",\"3550089362475695\",\"3549897523877864\",\"3549756045751486\",\"3549719639064459\",\"3549564726035910\",\"3549379539997223\",\"3549377979585685\",\"3549373109656624\"],\"uId\":1916364215,\"type\":3}";

                System.out.println("compare two string:" + temp.toString().equals(str));
                //compare two string:true
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(str);
                String s = new String(sb.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("s test:" + s);
                //s test:{"tags":[{"r_id":3553740735078269,"tag":"?????"},{"r_id":3555331928010955,"tag":"?????"},{"r_id":3555332033148401,"tag":"?????,??????????"}],"rids":"3555332033148401,3555331928010955,3553740735078269,3553509628288136,3552801450193593,3550638895838037,3550607615227068,3550334377352366,3550333965816322,3550315184067715,3550136490112256,3550098295918936,3550094449884887,3550094122996559,3550092986220398,3550090717120421,3550090532251655,3550089362475695,3549897523877864,3549756045751486,3549719639064459,3549564726035910,3549379539997223,3549377979585685,3549373109656624","idArr":["3555332033148401","3555331928010955","3553740735078269","3553509628288136","3552801450193593","3550638895838037","3550607615227068","3550334377352366","3550333965816322","3550315184067715","3550136490112256","3550098295918936","3550094449884887","3550094122996559","3550092986220398","3550090717120421","3550090532251655","3550089362475695","3549897523877864","3549756045751486","3549719639064459","3549564726035910","3549379539997223","3549377979585685","3549373109656624"],"uId":1916364215,"type":3}
                /*test code.*/

            } else{
                httpResponser.content = new String(temp.toString().getBytes(), ecod);
            } 

            httpResponser.urlString = urlString;  

            httpResponser.defaultPort = urlConnection.getURL().getDefaultPort();  
            httpResponser.file = urlConnection.getURL().getFile();  
            httpResponser.host = urlConnection.getURL().getHost();  
            httpResponser.path = urlConnection.getURL().getPath();  
            httpResponser.port = urlConnection.getURL().getPort();  
            httpResponser.protocol = urlConnection.getURL().getProtocol();  
            httpResponser.query = urlConnection.getURL().getQuery();  
            httpResponser.ref = urlConnection.getURL().getRef();  
            httpResponser.userInfo = urlConnection.getURL().getUserInfo();  

            httpResponser.contentEncoding = ecod;  
            httpResponser.code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();  
            httpResponser.message = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();  
            httpResponser.contentType = urlConnection.getContentType();  
            httpResponser.method = urlConnection.getRequestMethod();  
            httpResponser.connectTimeout = urlConnection.getConnectTimeout();  
            httpResponser.readTimeout = urlConnection.getReadTimeout();  

            return httpResponser;  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            throw e;  
        } finally {  
            if (urlConnection != null)  
                urlConnection.disconnect();  
        }  
    }  

    /** 
     * 默认的响应字符集 
     */  
    public String getDefaultContentEncoding() {  
        return this.defaultContentEncoding;  
    }  

    /** 
     * 设置默认的响应字符集 
     */  
    public void setDefaultContentEncoding(String defaultContentEncoding) {  
        this.defaultContentEncoding = defaultContentEncoding;  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str = "{\"tags\":[{\"r_id\":3553740735078269,\"tag\":\"再测试\"},{\"r_id\":3555331928010955,\"tag\":\"再测试\"},{\"r_id\":3555332033148401,\"tag\":\"再测试,测试好多个字符串\"}],\"rids\":\"3555332033148401,3555331928010955,3553740735078269,3553509628288136,3552801450193593,3550638895838037,3550607615227068,3550334377352366,3550333965816322,3550315184067715,3550136490112256,3550098295918936,3550094449884887,3550094122996559,3550092986220398,3550090717120421,3550090532251655,3550089362475695,3549897523877864,3549756045751486,3549719639064459,3549564726035910,3549379539997223,3549377979585685,3549373109656624\",\"idArr\":[\"3555332033148401\",\"3555331928010955\",\"3553740735078269\",\"3553509628288136\",\"3552801450193593\",\"3550638895838037\",\"3550607615227068\",\"3550334377352366\",\"3550333965816322\",\"3550315184067715\",\"3550136490112256\",\"3550098295918936\",\"3550094449884887\",\"3550094122996559\",\"3550092986220398\",\"3550090717120421\",\"3550090532251655\",\"3550089362475695\",\"3549897523877864\",\"3549756045751486\",\"3549719639064459\",\"3549564726035910\",\"3549379539997223\",\"3549377979585685\",\"3549373109656624\"],\"uId\":1916364215,\"type\":3}";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(str);
        String s = new String(sb.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("s test:" + s);
        //s test:{"tags":[{"r_id":3553740735078269,"tag":"再测试"},{"r_id":3555331928010955,"tag":"再测试"},{"r_id":3555332033148401,"tag":"再测试,测试好多个字符串"}],"rids":"3555332033148401,3555331928010955,3553740735078269,3553509628288136,3552801450193593,3550638895838037,3550607615227068,3550334377352366,3550333965816322,3550315184067715,3550136490112256,3550098295918936,3550094449884887,3550094122996559,3550092986220398,3550090717120421,3550090532251655,3550089362475695,3549897523877864,3549756045751486,3549719639064459,3549564726035910,3549379539997223,3549377979585685,3549373109656624","idArr":["3555332033148401","3555331928010955","3553740735078269","3553509628288136","3552801450193593","3550638895838037","3550607615227068","3550334377352366","3550333965816322","3550315184067715","3550136490112256","3550098295918936","3550094449884887","3550094122996559","3550092986220398","3550090717120421","3550090532251655","3550089362475695","3549897523877864","3549756045751486","3549719639064459","3549564726035910","3549379539997223","3549377979585685","3549373109656624"],"uId":1916364215,"type":3}
    }
}
```

Comment: I have find out the solution:          httpResponser.content = new String(temp.toString().getBytes(this.defaultContentEncoding), ecod);

Answer (score 0):

I have find out the solution,use the code below:

```
httpResponser.content = new String(temp.toString().getBytes(this.defaultContentEncoding), ecod);
```